# Opening pulldown section with button

Tags: html, wordpress, button

There is probably an answer for this but I have no idea of the terminology I would search for unfortunately!

Basically, there is a button on my Wordpress website at the top right which when clicked, pulls down a form to fill out. What's the easiest way of creating a button further down the page which would open that pulldown and take the user up there, presumably with an anchor? Simple HTML/CSS would be ideal because A: I can create a text box in the page layout creator and just paste the code in there and B: My coding knowledge is quite limited!

The website is www.harringtonsproperty.co.uk. The button in question is the BOOK A VALUATION at the top right.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be done with CSS alone. You need to use JavaScript.

Currently, the `'click'` event is described at the top of the [custom.js](http://www.harringtonsproperty.co.uk/wp-content/themes/harringtons/js/custom.js) file. You'll need to add an additional JS function into this file to achieve what you want. For starters/example:

```
jQuery('button#contactToggle2').click(function(e){  
    e.preventDefault();     
    if( jQuery('#contactSlide').css('display') == 'block' ) {       
        jQuery('#contactSlide').slideUp(500);       
    } else {        
        jQuery('#contactSlide').slideDown(500);
        // Handle scroll to top
        jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},800);
    }
})
```

You'll then need to give your new button an `id="contactToggle2"` in order for this to work. Again, this is just an example.

Comment: Okay, so just paste that code at the bottom of my custom.js file and give my new button that id and it should work?

Comment: Maybe. As I said, this is just an example. I haven't tested it, but the concept/answer is still correct. Use jQuery, and target a new button's `click` event.

Comment: If you paste that code in your file, it should be placed before the final `})`, to be within the `ready` function.

Comment: Bingo. Looks like it's working! Just gotta style the button now and it's job done. Thanks!